# Автоматический поиск дома по адресу Яндекс.Карты API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Загружается страница с встроенной картой от Yandex. Из базы получаю адрес дома и передаю его в скрипт, который находит этот дом на карте и ставит на его место baloon. Есть какое-то готовое решение это задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось что-то вроде этого:

```
ymaps.ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=' + "{{ settings.address }}", function(data) {
        var gobj = data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0];
        var gobj_name = gobj.GeoObject.description + ' - '+ gobj.GeoObject.name;
        var gobj_pos = gobj.GeoObject.Point.pos.split(' ').reverse();
        var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: gobj_pos,
            zoom: 16
        });
        var balloon = map.balloon.open(map.getCenter(), { content: gobj_name } );
    });
});
```

Где *{{ settings.address }}* - это адрес из базы данных.